# Oracle APEX 5.1 validation not executing

Tags: validation, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page that contains with a standard Save and Close button. I've written a page validation "PL/SQL Function (Returning  Error Text)", with the following settings:
"Always Execute" is "No"
Server Side Condition "When Button Pressed" is "Save".
I've included some debugging statements in the function body that write entries to a log table indicating progress through the function for my personal use.

The Save button has the following settings:
Action is "Submit Page"
Execute Validations is "Yes"

However, when the button is clicked (the page is submitted), the validation is not being executed - there are no database log table entries as expected, and when I look at the debug log for the page there are no entries that indicate the validation was run or that a return value had been received.

According to the Oracle documentation, these settings should fire the validation; any ideas why it's not running are appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problem in what you have said.  Can you set up a simple example of the issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: Run the page in debug mode; after pushing the "Save" button, view debug info - it might tell you what went wrong.

Comment: What happens if you remove the condition and set always execute to true?

Comment: This is too vague, we need more details to be able to debug, like code snippet of your code that is executed or not. Also, if you are referencing items in your code check they are spelled identically as on the page, if not the validation will validate and execute without problems but items values won't be correctly submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I had the database save process executing at the "After Page Submit" execution point, which happens before "Validating". Once I moved the database action to the "Processing" execution point (which happens after "Validating"), the validation executed as expected.

Thanks for everyone's response.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have a "Submit" button with action "Submit Page", "Execute Validations" toggled Yes. DB action process is in the "Processing" section already but the validation from "Validating" section still does not fire.